# Какую версию JDK скачать на mac?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста какой jdk выбрать если у меня macbook pro i5 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш мак на процессоре intel соответсвенно вам нужна версия x64, если бы ваш мак был на процессоре m1, m1pro etc., то была бы нужна версия arm.

Еще для установки jdk можно использовать [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) c его помощью можно устанавливать jdk через терминал.